# animate from display block to display inline

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Is it possible at all to use jquery or jquery ui to animate an unordered list from display block to display inline. So the list will smoothly transform to inline?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. No, there isn't a nice, simple, built-in way.

Comment: @Matt Ball  you should make it an answer `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. No, there isn't a nice, simple, built-in way.

Comment: I think it is relatively difficult to write a general-use animation that does this. Depending on the browser, a slew of different CSS properties can change depending on the `display`, such as `top`, `left`, `height`, `width`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Such a call to animate() would be valid. But which result *may* we expect? 
Animation of "top" from 0 to 1000 in 100 steps increases top by 10 each step.
What are the "steps" /"slices" between block and inline?

Comment: i have no idea, i was just wondering if there was a quick simple way... obviously not, ima have to sit here and mess about with positioning now =/

Comment: so sorry... but i'd love to have a look at the result. Very inspiring idea.

Comment: if I come up with a method, that would work in many scenarios, i shall post the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but for people who are looking at this thread, you can add a custom animation to the block property now.

```
.subnav-is-opened .main-nav__secondary-nav {
   display: block;
   -webkit-animation: showNav 250ms ease-in-out both;
   -animation: showNav 250ms ease-in-out both;
 }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Demo - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/